# StreamedResponse file not found error

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm trying to export big table (100 000 rows into a CSV file) using laravel StreamedResponse chunk method. With the code pasted below it's not working fine and showing the below error .

[image]

> File not found Firefox can’t find the file at
>   http://laravel/allExport2. Check the file name for capitalization or
>   other typing errors. Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or
>   deleted.

**Controller**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type'        => 'text/csv',
            'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=test.csv',
            'Expires'             => '0',
            'Pragma'              => 'public',
        );

        $response = new StreamedResponse(function(){
            // Open output stream
            $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            // Add CSV headers
            fputcsv($handle, [
                "invoice_number",
                "title",
            ]);


            Order::chunk(500, function($orders) use($handle) {
                    foreach ($orders as $user) {
                        // Add a new row with data
                        fputcsv($handle, [
                            $user->invoice_number,
                            $user->courtesy_title,
                        ]);
                    }
                });

            // Close the output stream
            fclose($handle);
        }, 200, $headers);

        return $response->send();
```

Comment: Try just returning the response, not using `->send()`, `->send()` should be used injunction with `->setCallback()`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy showing the same error file not found.

Comment: @meera1002, check your routes (may be you are trying to open nonexisting route), ensure that your code is called. Replace it with something simple, like `echo "Hello world";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, your browser received 404 error.

There are a few reasons for that.

1. Check your routes, confirm that you're trying to access the existing one. Also, note that the routes are case sensitive. It means `Route::get('SuPeRCRaZyPaGe', function (){...})` will not be accessible for `/supercrazypage` or `/SuperCrazyPage`.
2. Check middlewares, may be it throws not found exception or `abort(404)`.
3. Check your code, if you're working with Eloquent models and have `findOrFail` or `firstOrFail` cases. Check them, they can throw ModelNotFoundException (converted into 404 error).

And of course don't forget to check laravel's log (`~/storage/logs/laravel.log`) and enable debug settings.